# Select HTML tag with multiple values in the same attribute

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I'm using HtmlAgilityPack and I`m having some troubles to search nodes with multiple values in the same attribute.. for example:

```
<span class="test1 test2 test3">blah</span>
```

And if I try to make something like this:

```
SelectSingleNode (.... [@class='test1']
```

It doesn't work, only if I search for all classes together like:

```
SelectSingleNode (.... [@class='test1 test2 test3']
```

Any way to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done!

I can use something like this:

```
SelectSingleNode("//span[contains(@class, 'test1')]");
```